# Does authentication for USB keyboards exist?

Tags: physical-access, keyboard

I think bluetooth has an authentication measure. As a user, when I get a new bluetooth keyboard, I have to:

1. Go to my computer, search for bluetooth devices
2. Put my keyboard in "pairing mode"
3. My computer displays some random numbers which I have to enter in the keyboard

I am hoping that then there is an authentication between the keyboard and the computer happening which makes it hard to execute man in the middle (MITM) attacks on my keyboard usage.

For USB-keyboards, however, I haven't ever noticed anything like that (on Ubuntu). If a USB keyboard is connected to a computer and exchanged by an attacker with a similar looking one with a keylogger, I would not notice.

Do USB keyboards exist which authenticate themselves in a similar way like bluetooth keyboards?

Comment: Look into `usbguard`. It looks for several low-level criteria about the USB device, including a hash of something. Not sure how forgable those components are.